# How to make cluster local request from one service to another in Knative?

Tags: knative

I have followed the this guide https://knative.dev/docs/serving/cluster-local-route/ to make a service cluster-local.

I am trying to access that service from another service that is inside the cluster using curl command but i always *get could not resolve host* error.

I have tried to make request with the  *curl* *helloworld-default.svc.cluster* and *curl -H "Host: helloworld-go.default.svc.cluster*" http://< cluster_ip > command.

I am missing something?
Do i need to make any configuration to Istio virtualService to make it work?
(I am running Knative inside GKE)

Comment: the cluster domain is usually `cluster.local`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the `.local` and it should work.

```
curl -H "Host: helloworld-go.default.svc.cluster.local" http://< cluster_ip >
```

But you should be able to drop the ClusterIP entirely as you are making the request from within the cluster. Basically execute:

```
curl helloworld-go.default.svc.cluster.local
```

The DNS `helloworld-go.default.svc.cluster.local` will be resolved by the Kubernetes DNS resolution mechanism.

---

It's important to specify the HOST header only on **ingress traffic** (public traffic entering into private traffic).

Details: The Knative Service creates a Route CRD, which creates a ClusterIngress which will be picked up by a controller (by default istio-network) to configure the Ingress Gateway (using another CRD in istio's case VirtualService). 
Ingress Gateways routing is based on the HOST header.

Comment: Thank for the response, the problem was that the default installation of Knative at GKE didn't have cluster local gateway installed.

Comment: Cool, I'd love to see a longer answer so that I can learn from it 